# Selenium Python - can locate table (bring back no. rows/cols) but can't find specific element to click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Thanks already to the users who have helped me on this piece of work. I am navigating to the url enfa.co.uk. I use ChromeDriver with Selenium in Python and navigate (via iframe) to click on the 'Clubs' link from the left hand menu, then switch iframes to select a drop-down value 'Select Club = Shrewsbury Town' and then click on a specific season '1950/51'.

This takes me to a table for which I am trying to click on a value under the column 'Res'. This would take me to further data (I have to login to access this data, but either way, a user clicking on this link would take them to the subscribe page which also has the desired result).

I have checked that I am in within the expected table by calculating the number of rows/columns and this matches my expectations (97/9). However when I try and click on the element required (in this example, the Res is 0-0 which should correspond to row 7 / column 7) I receive a traceback stating that the element is not interactable. Similarly if I try and print this element it shows as blank. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
#utilise chrome driver to open specified webpage
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/philthomas/Desktop/web/chromedriver")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http:enfa.co.uk")
#switch to specific iframe and click on 'clubs' button on left hand menu
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"left")))
ClubsLink = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),' Clubs')]")))

ClubsLink.click()
#return from iframe
driver.switch_to.default_content()
#Switch to main iframe
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"main")))
#find drop-down menu and choose 'Team'
teamselect=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"team")))
select_box = Select(teamselect)
select_box.select_by_visible_text("Shrewsbury Town")
#ChooseSeason
season=WebDriverWait(driver,10)until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(text(),'1950/51')]")))

season.click()
#count number of rows & columns in table to check:
rows=len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[7]/table/tbody/tr"))
cols=len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[7]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td"))
print('No of rows in table:', rows)
print('No of columns in table:', cols)
#click on specific Res - in this case, 0-0 Aug 19th v Scunthorpe
match=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/div[7]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[7]/a")))

match.click()
print('Check:', value)
```

HTML of required element:

[image: HTML]

Traceback error:

[image: Traceback]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is present in the html before it's visible, so `EC.presence_of_element_located` is true but the element is still hidden and can't be clicked. Use `EC.visibility_of_element_located` instead

```
match = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[7]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[7]/a")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find updated solution. Explicit wait method needs to be change while clicking on the elements.

Also I have updated code to switch to default content before switching to main frame

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
#utilise chrome driver to open specified webpage
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http:enfa.co.uk")
#switch to specific iframe and click on 'clubs' button on left hand menu
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"left")))
ClubsLink=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Clubs')]")))
ClubsLink.click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()


#Switch to main iframe
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"main")))
#find drop-down menu and choose 'Team'
teamselect=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"team")))
select_box = Select(teamselect)
select_box.select_by_visible_text("Shrewsbury Town")
season=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(text(),'1950/51')]")))

season.click()
#count number of rows & columns in table to check:
rows=len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[7]/table/tbody/tr"))
cols=len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[7]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td"))
print('No of rows in table:', rows)
print('No of columns in table:', cols)
#click on specific Res - in this case, 0-0 Aug 19th v Scunthorpe
match=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(text(),'Scunthorpe & Lindsey Utd')]")))
match.click()
```

Comment: you can also use `/html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/div[7]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[7]/td[5]/a[1]` Abs XPath to click on `Scunthorpe & Lindsey Utd`